# Convert a 100 x 100 Matrix to 100 x 1 Matrix/Vector/Dataframe Preserving Column/Row Label Combination

Tags: r

What I am trying to acheive is partially done correctly by `unlist()`. However, I wish to preserve both row and column names. **`unmatrix()`** does this, but it does vice-versa of what I want. Thus, if I have a **df** as follow:

```
      User1 User2 User3
Time1 1.5   2.5   3.5
Time2 7.8   9.2   10
Time3 4.5   8.8   1.4
```

What I want to receive is:

```
User1:Time1 1.5
User1:Time2 7.8
User1:Time3 4.5
User2:Time1 2.5
User2:Time2 9.2
User2:Time3 8.8
User3:Time1 3.5
User3:Time2 10
User3:Time3 1.4
```

When I use `unlist()` it only preserves column names, but not row names. Is there any other way to do this? `**unmatrix()**` exactly does what I want to do, but instead of giving me User1:Time1, it gives me Time1:User1, i.e. instead of giving me column.name:row.name it is giving me row.name:column.name

**####EDIT####**

`unmatrix(t(as.matrix(df)))` does the right thing, BUT then the order of elements is NOT what I want.

Comment: you can tweak the code of `unmatrix` :: `m <- as.matrix(df) ;
setNames(c(m), t(outer(colnames(m), rownames(m), paste, sep = ":") ))`

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, just use `sort()` on `names()`after `unmatrix()`:

```
library(gdata)
um <- unmatrix(t(as.matrix(df)))
um[sort(names(um))]
User1:Time1 User1:Time2 User1:Time3 User2:Time1 User2:Time2 User2:Time3 User3:Time1 User3:Time2 User3:Time3 
    1.5         7.8         4.5         2.5         9.2         8.8         3.5        10.0         1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

A little lengthier using dplyr, reshape2

```
tbl <- read.table( row.names=NULL, text=
"User1 User2 User3
Time1 1.5   2.5   3.5
Time2 7.8   9.2   10
Time3 4.5   8.8   1.4
")
names(tbl)[1] <- "label"
require(dplyr, reshape2)                 
result <- tbl %>% 
  melt() %>% 
  mutate(label=paste0(label, ":", variable), value=value) %>%
  select (-variable)
result

        label value
1 Time1:User1   1.5
2 Time2:User1   7.8
3 Time3:User1   4.5
4 Time1:User2   2.5
5 Time2:User2   9.2
6 Time3:User2   8.8
7 Time1:User3   3.5
8 Time2:User3  10.0
9 Time3:User3   1.4
```